# Conversion from Maxima (Mathematica) to python

Tags: python

Did you know the script (program) that converts the code of **Maxima** (mathematical formula processing software) to **Python**? Does **Maxima** have the ability to convert to **Fortran**?
Since the formula processing software is easy input for fractions, I frequently use, but when I try to manually convert these fractions to **python** with **slashes**, it is (for me) something withering.

Comment: This site is for questions about *Mathematica*. *Maxima* is a different software system.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't concern Mathematica.

Comment: Why has this migrated from *Mathematica* to Mathematics? ... oh, because it concerns maxima!

Comment: Regarding Fortran: http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_58.html Regarding Python, the easiest would be to write a Python program to parse Maxima output, or to convert your program to [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/) if it's feasible. But none of this has anything to do on MSE.

Comment: Or maybe try [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/), which is a Python program with bindings to Maxima (I can't help much with it as I never used it).

Answer (score 1):

There is a maxima to python translation tool built into maxima. The documentation is at: https://maxima.sourceforge.io/docs/manual/maxima_308.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).